# How can i used @Component or @Autowired on below code

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

```
`public abstract class A {
    methodA();
    methodB();
 }`

`public class B {
    private A aa
    public B(A aaa) {
       this.aa = aaa;
    }
 }`
```

Above code is abstract class. Below is one of the class that use abstract class in Constructor Parameter.

`I need to change the @Component and @Autowired annotation on above Java code in Springboot Project. If you have any suggestion, please help me to guide the solution Thank you.`

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Component for any classes that extends A class and using @Autowire above of any usage of A class

Comment: That was not the right one. Given code is Simple Java abstract class and using abstract class in another class with Constructor Parameter.